# wanting to use C++ WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() in Windows Mobile?

Tags: c++, windows-mobile

This function WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId() is compiled fine on Win32, but when I compile for Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK and it has error.  Is there a similar function to this for Windows Mobile platform?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should a single user, single session OS should provide a WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId function?

I am sorry, but there is no such function in Windows Mobile and there is no need for it. So you cannot use WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId on any Windows Mobile device.

Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: You are right.  On Windows 7, it can have multiple users can login to the PC while on mobile device is only for single user.  Thanks.